# c# code to get the data from .xlsx file and store it into an int[]

Tags: c#

i am try to get data from excel file and save it in 
int [] array=new int[9];
 want to do this using for loop , in order to get value from file "one row at a time" . i done with reading data fro file but couldont store it into int [] through iteration.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string i="B1410";
        string j="J1410";
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
   Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = 

    xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"E:\Normalized_sheet1.xlsx");
        string currentsheet = "Sheet1";
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[currentsheet];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.get_Range(i, j.ToString());
        Object[,] valueArray = 

     (Object[,])xlRange.get_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.
    xlRangeValueDefault);
      int[] array = new int[9];

       array =  Convert.ToInt32((Object[,])xlRange.get_Value
                 (Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeV    
                  alueDefault.ToString()));   //Error
        //want to enter values row wise one by one through loop


       //close the workbook 

        xlWorkbook.Close(false);

        // Release Com object by decrementing the reference count

        xlApp.Quit();
        Console.ReadLine();

   }
```

Comment: Now you've deleted the for loop altogether!  I have no idea what you're doing, trying to to or what's actually happening.  Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try asking a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Your array is only scoped to the for loop.

```
for (int k = 1; k < 500; k++)
{
    int[] array = new int[9];
}
```

Declare it outside.

```
int[] array = new int[9];
for (int k = 1; k < 500; k++)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank I'm afraid you're going to have to put up a clearer example of what you're expecting to happen and what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is only 9 elements long, but `k` can by up to `499`.  You can't insert one element into this array per iteration of the for loop as you'll get in `IndexOutOfBoundsException` thrown.

`array` probably needs to be the same size as the max value of `k`, i.e. 499.

Comment: int[] value = new int[9]; 
value=Convert.ToInt32((Object[,])xlRange.get_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault.ToString()));   //  i want to store the values  in object into arrayas integers